# Update canvas in ActionBaryActivity

Tags: android, canvas

I'm having issues updating the canvas after I call drawLine();

Here is the code I have:

```
public class Map extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Paint p = new Paint();
        Log.v("Tag", "in here");
        Log.v("Tag", Integer.toString(customView.lines.size()));
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_undo:
                customView.lines.remove(customView.lines.size() - 1);
                Canvas c = new Canvas();
                for (Line line: customView.lines){
                    Log.v("Tag", "in here2");

                    c.drawLine(line.startX,line.startY,line.endX,line.endY,p);
                }

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like the canvas to be updated directly after call this method. However the only way I know how to do this is use the invalidate() method and this can only be done in a View. Any suggestions on how to make this work? Very new to android development.

THanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're not drawing on anything. 
You'll need to implement a custom View, something you probably already have looking at your code, which allows you to draw a line.

```
public class CustomDrawableView extends View {

     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            for (Line line: customView.lines){
                Log.v("Tag", "in here2");

                c.drawLine(line.startX,line.startY,line.endX,line.endY,p);
            }
     }
}
```

Have a look at following code on GitHub:
[YetAnotherDrawableDemo](https://github.com/sergedesmedt/YetAnotherAndroidDemo/blob/master/YetAnotherDrawableDemo/src/main/java/sde/android/yadd/CustomDrawableView.java)

Read following links:
[Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html),
[Canvas and Drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html)

Comment: I already do have a view. However, the problem is that I need to draw something after getting a result from the MenuItem. For instance I have MenuItem that is "draw". How do I communicate that information between the Activity and the view?

Comment: Add a method which sets a Boolean or something, check the Boolean in the onDraw method, if it's true draw the lines, it not then don't. In the handler of the MenuItem, call this method on the View